# calling a function from outside a thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having problem calling destroy function of a top window which is in a thread in Python 3. It doesn't destroy the window and seems to be stalled in a loop or something. Here is my code for the class:

```
class clientUI(Thread):
    sSock = None
    mID = 0
    yID = 0

    def __init__(self, sendSock, myID, yourID, q, looptime = 1.0/60):
        self.q = q
        self.timeout = looptime
        self.sSock = sendSock
        self.mID = myID
        self.yID = yourID
        self.first_click = True;
        super(clientUI, self).__init__()

    def onThread(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.q.put((function, args, kwargs))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                function, args, kwargs = self.q.get(timeout=self.timeout)
                function(*args, **kwargs)
            except queue.Empty:
                self.idle()

    def idle(self):
        self.initDisplay()
        self.ui_input.insert(tkinter.END, "<Enter message>")
        self.ui_top.mainloop()

    def _eventDeleteDisplay(self):
        self.ui_top.pack_forget()
        self.ui_top.destroy()
    def eventDeleteDisplay(self):
        self.onThread(self._eventDeleteDisplay)
```

and here is how I create the thread:

```
def open_chat(sendSock, myID, yourID):
    q = queue.Queue()
    ui = clientUI(sendSock, myID, yourID, q, 1.0/60)
    try:
        ui.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Caught CTRL-C, shutting down client")
        ui.eventDeleteDisplay()
    return ui
```

I want to be able to call the eventDeleteDisplay() fucntion from the main thread which destroys the window and also to able to terminate the thread when I call it, but none of those happen. All things go well but the the window is still there and the thread doesn't terminate. Here is how I call the function from the main thread:

```
ui.eventDeleteDisplay()
```

Comment: All tkinter code needs to run in the same thread that creates the window. Tkinter isn't designed to work from two different threads.

Comment: @BryanOakley you mean I can't call that function from my main thread? so what should I do?